# Field name convention

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use field name with bracket , for example: distance(a).
the indexing work fine, but when I  query:

```
GET /search
{
   "query":
       {
         "query_string":"distance(a):*"
       }
}
```

I got error.
in field without bracket it's work fine.
Someone know how can I use field name with bracket?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so `(` is a reserved character in Elasticsearch and to use it in a query you'll have to escape it. A list of reserved characters can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters). So normally you could just escape it with `\`, but in order for the escape character to get though the REST API you have to double escape it with `\\`.

I just tested the following query in my sandbox:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "distance\\(a\\):*"
    }
  }
}
```